# Why won't my Bootstrap CSS divs stack nicely?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with Bootstrap which some people here seem to know about. I have set up the following two divs according to the basic "row" class grid conventions, yet they are not stacking as expected when I reduce the size of the browser screen. They just stay fixed.

Update:

Bootstrap became responsive when I linked to the bootstrap-responsive.css file, as suggested below.

However, the boxes stretch beyond the maximum grid size I had intended and set (i.e. the default of 940px which came in the original installation and I re-affirmed by compiling it all again with LESS). Moreover, it actually stretched beyond the far-right extent of the browser window. Screenshot from Chrome (17.0.963.56) (more markup visible in developer tools in screenshot):

http://static.inky.ws/image/1457/image.jpg

This happens with and without the inclusion of:

Maybe I am using bootstrap in the wrong way, but I want it to behave responsively on selected divs (classed as "row", "spanX", etc.) but to stop at the max grid width of my choosing, and at least to stop at the far extent of the window!

Thanks again for your time,
Matt

HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid"><!-- Intro begin -->
    <div class="span6">
        <p style="font-size: 18px;">
            <strong><span style="font-size: 20px;">Mingo makes it easy to share food with other people in your area.</span></strong>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="span6">
        <!--<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}images/pics/how_it_works.png" width="350px" style="margin-right: 20px;" />-->
        <div style="background-color: #E7F5DF; height: 250px; padding: 8px; border-radius: 8px;">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="float: right;">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Save time, save money</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div style="width: 99.5%; height: 87.5%; background-color: #c6e3b6; margin: 9.5% 0 0; border-radius: 8px; moz-border-radius: 8px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- Intro end -->
```

Comment: What do you mean "stack"? Do you want the divs to appear side-by-side?

Comment: I mean like they do in the example on the website: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html under default grid system. They also don't grow when the window is sized up.

Comment: Then it appears you mean side-by-side, and not stacked. Stacked means one on top of another. This works fine for me. Did you recheck the files you are including?

Comment: What I mean is that, at the smallest size, according to Bootstrap and demonstrated on their site, all divs should be forced to stack on one another, but that is not happening in my implementation. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you have only included the `bootstrap.css` stylesheet and not the `bootstrap-responsive.css` stylesheet?

If that is the case, try to include both.

With your HTML markup and both CSS files, it seems to works : http://jsfiddle.net/TimPetricola/KFnxs/

Comment: Yes, thanks, that helped by allowing it to stack, but brought out other problems described above in the edit to my original question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to include

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in your html header, otherwise the mobile browsers zoom out rather then changing the layout to fit the screen width.

Comment: I did that, but it didn't seem to change anything. Thanks though.